# How to auto publish on application's wall using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have requirement that whatever I store on server database (like adding new question), it should auto publish to application's wall so that users who likes application can see regular updates.

How is it possible using PHP?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: He suggests your question can have better answers there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a listener that will read the new changes on db or from the interface where u are setting the data for the database call the fb api and post it inmediatly... in that case would be something like this.

```
 $autpost = array('message' => ' message',
    'name' => 'This is my demo',
    'caption' => "Caption ",
    'link' => 'http://facebook.com',
    'description' => 'description',
    'picture' => 'http://somesite.picture.jpg',
    'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
    'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
    );    
    $result = $facebook->api('/fanpage id/feed/', 'post', $wall_post);
```